# What is the use of okta-shared-transaction-storage key/value

Tags: reactjs, authentication, okta, okta-api

I am using okta-auth-js library with react.
Can anyone help me understand the use of okta-shared-transaction-storage key/value in localStorage? I tried searching in the documentation and google, but unable to find any useful information about this.

Comment: No idea, but if you are really interested/concerned, you can check their Github repo to find it out

Comment: Thanks. But I already did that. There are very few references to this and it really doesn't explain what is the purpose of it.

Comment: You can also try to ask through developers@okta.com to potentially get an answer